# How can I compile F# or C# code into web assembly

Tags: f#, webassembly

I want to generate bits of F# (using FCS) or C# (using ?) on the fly and compile them into web assembly. I will later run said web assembly module from a .NET host.

I'm able to run web assembly modules using wasmtime. However, I cannot find a library that allows me to build a wasm module from some arbitrary code (string), is it possible to do this?

UPDATE: done some more reading and if I understand it correctly, .NET has no C#/F# -> WASM compiler but instead it uses mono compiled to wasm and runs regular IL.

If I understand it correctly mono wasm only runs on a javascript environment: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20063. So I guess what I want to do is not possible atm.

Happy to be corrected on this, as I'm really hoping there is a way to using F# for scripting (while running as a wasm module).

Comment: Maybe you should look at how Bolero does this with F#.

Comment: Mono WASM is the in-production method but it doesn't fully compile the code to WASM - it has missing bits and so deploys the IL too and interprets it! NativeAOT is full AOT compilation to WASM and that is in development in https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab.